# numpy functions that can/cannot be used on a compressed sparse row (CSR) matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, diagonal

I am a newbie in Python and I have a (probably very naive) question. I have a CSR (compressed sparse row) matrix to work on (let's name it `M`), and looks like some functions that are designed for a 2d numpy array manipulation work for my matrix while some others do not.

For example, `numpy.sum(M, axis=0)` works fine while `numpy.diagonal(M)` gives an error saying `{ValueError}diag requires an array of at least two dimensions`.

So is there a rationale behind why one matrix function works on `M` while the other does not?

And a bonus question is, how to get the diagonal elements from a CSR matrix given the above `numpy.diagonal` does not work for it?

Comment: As a general rule, use the functions and methods provided by `sparse` where possible.  Sparse matrices are not subclasses of `ndarray`, so `numpy` functions do not as a rule work on these matrices, especially if they first try to turn their inputs into arrays, e.g. with `np.asarray(yourmatrix)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `np.diagonal` is:

```
return asanyarray(a).diagonal(offset=offset, axis1=axis1, axis2=axis2)
```

That is, it first tries to turn the argument into an array, for example if it is a list of lists.  But that isn't the right way to turn a sparse matrix into a `ndarray`.

```
In [33]: from scipy import sparse                                               
In [34]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(np.eye(3))                                       
In [35]: M                                                                      
Out[35]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [36]: M.A                                  # right                                  
Out[36]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
In [37]: np.asanyarray(M)                    # wrong                           
Out[37]: 
array(<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

The correct way to use `np.diagonal` is:

```
In [38]: np.diagonal(M.A)                                                       
Out[38]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

But no need for that.  `M` already has a `diagonal` method:

```
In [39]: M.diagonal()                                                           
Out[39]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

`np.sum` does work, because it delegates the action to a method (look at its code):

```
In [40]: M.sum(axis=0)                                                          
Out[40]: matrix([[1., 1., 1.]])
In [41]: np.sum(M, axis=0)                                                      
Out[41]: matrix([[1., 1., 1.]])
```

As a general rule, try to use `sparse` functions and methods on sparse matrices.  Don't count on `numpy` functions to work right.  `sparse` is built on `numpy`, but `numpy` does not 'know' about `sparse`.