# Sparse matrix diagonalisation using Numpy Linalg package

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, lanczos

What is the maximum size of a sparse matrix that can be diagonalized using Numpy Linalg package?

I have been working with exact diagonalisation methods such as Lanczos and Arnoldi in the context of diagonalizing my Hamiltonian matrices.

Recently I have started to use Numpy's linalg to do these numerical calculations.

I have been wondering about, what would be the maximum size of a very sparse matrix that can be diagonalised using Numpy. Are there any hacks to get beyond a certain limit and is it possible to get the code to work faster are there any best practices on this kind of coding with numpy?

Comment: It's not clear whether you have the scipy sparse matrices in mind or not.  But if you do, you should look at the `scipy.sparse.linalg` functions rather than the numpy.linalg ones.

Comment: Also see my comments for https://stackoverflow.com/q/55009318/901925

Comment: Any idea what would be the maximum size of a matrix that I could diagonalise using numpy

Comment: NumPy's diagonalization routines (and its array representation) don't take advantage of sparsity at all.